# Possible Memory Leak in CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm referring to the following links :https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/StreamTransformationFilter and https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode

In line `StringSource string_source(encypted_data, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new StringSink(plain_data)));` we are creating the objects of class StreamTransformationFilter and StringSink on heap using `new` operator; however we are not deleting them. Shouldn't it cause memory leak as their is no delete operation.

Should I replace

```cpp
StringSource string_source(plain_data, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption, new StringSink(encypted_data)));
```

with the following code

```cpp
try
{
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption   encryption(this->aes_key.data(), this->aes_key.size(), this->aes_iv.data(), this->aes_iv.size())
    CryptoPP::StringSink                            string_sink(encypted_data);
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter            stf_encryptor(encryption, string_sink);
    CryptoPP::StringSource                          string_source(plain_data, true, stf_encryptor);
}
```

to avoid memory link; so that as soon as the try block is exited destructor on classes `CryptoPP::StringSink`, `CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter` and `CryptoPP::StringSource` will be called.

Program :

```cpp
std::optional<std::string> Cryptography::decrypt_data(const std::string& encypted_data)
{
    std::optional<std::string> plain_data { std::nullopt };
    try
    {
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption   decryption(this->aes_key.data(), this->aes_key.size(), this->aes_iv.data(), this->aes_iv.size())
        StringSource string_source(encypted_data, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new StringSink(plain_data)));
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        spdlog::error("CryptoPP Exception in Cryptography::decrypt_data : {}", ex.what());
#endif
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        spdlog::error("Exception in Cryptography::decrypt_data : {}", ex.what());
#endif
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
    }
    return plain_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a filter/sink to the constructor of a filer/source it takes ownership of the pointer and will delete it on destruction.

In your example `StringSource` deletes the `StreamTransformationFilter` which in turn deletes the `StringSink`